# How to allow user to edit formatted text inside an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an app where I would like users to be able to review an existing string in a `<p></p>` element, `mouseover` on the text to edit it, and see the edited version when they `mouseout`.

Right now I am doing that in Javascript replacing the `<p>` with `<textarea>`.  I populate the `<textarea>` by setting its `innerHTML` to that of the `<p>` element.  That works fine except that the text appear as HTML rather than as formatted text.

So for example a user might have entered something like:

```
"An old silent pond...
A frog jumps into the pond,
splash! Silence again."
```

Then when the time comes to edit the text, it would appear as:

```
"An old silent pond...<br>A frog jumps into the pond,<br>splash! Silence again."
```

Is there a way to make sure that what is displayed for editing is interpreted HTML / formatted text rather than raw HTML?  I do need the formatting to be interpreted - I don't want to just strip out the HTML tags.

PS:  I assume that `textarea` is the right way to create a window to edit some text, but I'm not married to it.

Comment: Have you tried getting `.innerHTML().text()` or just `.text()`?

Comment: where is the text coming from to begin with? this same textarea?

Comment: @Ares - no, I'm not familiar with that.  I need to look it up.

Comment: @Sebas - The text comes from a previous form or a DB pull.

Comment: I dont know if `textarea` supports the display of html formatted text?

Comment: well what if the user actually wants to write "<br>", should it be interpreted?

Comment: @Sebas - In that case the `<>` would have been escaped, and yes they should be interpreted when played back.

Comment: By intepreted i meant "changed into a line feed". You can't escape it and interprete it at the same time.

Comment: @Sebas - sorry I wasn't clear.  If the user has typed "<br", then he should see "<br>", not "&lt;br&gt;" - but if he entered a line change, he should see a line change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to edit the text while seeing and retaining the formatting?  This is not something that can be done in a plain `<textarea>` -- you may want to look at wysiwyg editors such as [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com)

Another possibility is the HTML5 [contenteditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) attribute, and a javascript polyfill to support pre-HTML5 browsers.

---

See [Storing the Changes](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/#storing-changes) for a basic suggestion for saving the changes made in a `contenteditable` section, or search the web for `save contenteditable changes` for many articles on the subject.

---

Also, [Using the HTML5 attribute "contenteditable" to create a WYSIWYG](http://marakana.com/s/post/1096/using_the_html5_attribute_contenteditable_to_create_a_wysiwyg) walks through building up a simplistic editor (Now with Plain Ugly Buttons!)

Comment: Wow, it looks like that `contenteditable` attribute is pretty much exactly what I would need.  What's the catch?  :-)

Comment: The catch is that it's not a form field -- you need to do an AJAX style save yourself.

Comment: It was never meant to be a form field anyway, so that's OK.

Comment: TinyMCE and CKEditor are examples of those tools that allow web users to format some text, right?  I'll need to look into those eventually, thank you for the pointer.

Comment: @JDelage, yes, those can be attached to a `<textarea>` in a form and they will hide the original control and replace it with a fancy editor. When the form is submitted the content of the wysiwyg is shoveled into the original textarea and gets sent as part of the `POST` data. I use TinyMCE in my current project.

Comment: Wow, this attribute - `contenteditable` - is perfect for my needs.  This is beautiful.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

If available, set `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

```
textarea.textContent = p.innerHTML;
```

If you need to support IE8, use `innerText` if `textContent` is not there.

http://jsfiddle.net/yUMtj/

EDIT: As @RobG indicates, use `.value` instead of `.textContent` for even better compatibility.

Comment: the stuff inside a textarea element is its **value**. Of course browsers are tolerant so most probably set the innerHTML property to the value also. The textContent property is not supported by all browsers in use, therefore the value property is by far the best to use.

Comment: @JDelage how do you play to display colored text in the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

The content of a [textarea element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-textarea-element) isn't parsed as HTML. There are a number of HTML based editors available, Google is your friend.

A textarea element's content is its value. The HTML specification does not define innerHTML, textContent or innerText properties for textarea elements so you should use the value property to access the value.